# Netgear VLANs' setup with PVID

Tags: vlan, netgear-prosafe

Due to the scope of a current project, I need to setup VLANs in a few small locations. I don't have a lot experience, and even less time, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Netgear SRX5308 [DHCP] => Netgear GS728TSB => Netgear GS110TP => Netgear GS105E => various devices
```

There are quite a few GS105Es, and each has connected a Wi-Fi AP connected, broadcasting a tagged SSID. Also, there is a smart TV and an Apple TV connected to each as well.

I need to have each port to have a different default (native/management) VLAN.

So for ports on the GS105Es, I created VLANs 101, 102, 103, 104, and 201:

- 101 - port setup Untagged - port1, Tagged -port5 (leading to GS110TP)
- 102 - port setup Untagged - port2, Tagged -port5 (leading to GS110TP)
- 103 - port setup Untagged - port3, Tagged -port5 (leading to GS110TP)
- 104 - port setup Untagged - port4, Tagged -port5 (leading to GS110TP)
- 201 - port setup Tagged - port 1 and port 5 ( for tagged SSID)

and changed the PVID:

- port1 - PVID 101
- port2 - PVID 102
- port3 - PVID 103
- port4 - PVID 104

I have different a DHCP scope for each, so, for example. 192.168.101.x for VLAN 101.

Will VLAN unaware devices on different ports be able to talk to one to another since they will be on different subnets?

Am I missing something? Is there a different way of separating them?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish with this configuration?  My gut tells me there's a better/simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems about right for NetGear smart switches.
I've not built a replica of the above, but did some testing as I've found NetGear don't seem to be consistent with other vendors described in most literature. 
Here's a simple recipe for NG smart switches (GS108Ev3 and JGS524PE) per port:
 0 or one marked U for a VID with PVID matching; used to link untagged sources to a VLAN
 0 or more marked T for a VID, the PVID irrelavent; Used to link tagged sources to VLAN
The PVID on a T is different behaviour to that suggested in many texts (different vendors' probably)

Hope this helps